# how to print hash keys which dont have values?

Tags: perl

I want to print keys in hash which don't have values. How to achieve this in perl?

e.g.

```
my %hash = ( Lemon  => "",
             Orange => "orange",
             Lime   => "" );
```

I want to print keys Lemon & Lime only.

Comment: traverse the hash put the condition and print the keys or use grep to do this

Comment: What if you had `Tangerine => undef` ?  Would you also want to print "Tangerine"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` for whatever condition you like. All your keys have values, so I'm assuming you mean "which have values that are empty strings".

```
print "$_\n" foreach grep { $hash{$_} eq ""  } keys %hash;
```

Comment: `say for grep ! $hash{$_}, keys %hash;` in 5.10+

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the keys, printing each one with a blank/`undef` value:

```
$hash{$_} || say for keys %hash;
```

If you don't want `undef`:

```
$hash{$_} eq '' && say for keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see, that empty string in perl is false equivalent(perl hasnt bool types).
So:

```
my $var = '';
if ($var) {
    print 'true'
}
else {
    print 'false'
}
```

Result will be false. 
You can solve your trouble with this code:

```
my %hash = (
    Lemon  => "",
    Orange => "orange",
    Lime   => ""
);
foreach (keys %hash) {
    print 'empty key: ', $_, "\n" if !$hash{$_};
}
```

It will handle undef also.

Answer (score 0):

Or just as a little loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = ( Lemon  => "",
             Orange => "orange",
             Lime   => "" );


for my $key (sort keys %hash) { 
    if ($hash{$key} eq "")  {print "$key\t$hash{$key}\n"}
}
```

Output:

```
Lemon   
Lime
```

Comment: Does output contains key name too?
'Empty' value: ?
'Empty' value: ?

Comment: I was thinking for "Existing" or "Defined" to check whether they keys contain values or not & if not print them.

Comment: It will do exactly that now (see change)